# Top-k preference Query in Real road network Simulation Framework tool

Tags: java, database, simulation, spatial-query

I want to learn simulation for my paper work. My research area deals with top-k preference query in road networks, but I tried to mail all the authors about their framework but none replied regarding that. Therefore, I would like to ask whether I have to make my own simulation tool or there exist already an simulation tool so that I can learn it to modify it and use it. Please help me

Comment: No. This isn't the place to ask such questions.